# Completion of Function Field $K$ isomorphic to $\kappa_A((T))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, $K$ a function field over $k$, $A=(A,m)$ a discrete valuation ring of rank one with residue field $\kappa_A=A/m$ such that
$k \subset A \subset K$ and the fraction field  of $A$ is $K$.

Let $\widehat{K}$ be the completion
of $K$ for $A$. More precisely it's the fraction field of $\widehat{A}_m$, the completion of $A$ with respect $m$. Why the completion $\widehat{K}$ is isomorphic to $\kappa_A((T))$?
(Source:  [Unramified cohomology and rationality problems](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Epeyre/publications/textes/unramified.pdf) by Emmanuel Peyre)

Obviously we have a map $k \to \kappa_A$. Let $t$ be the parameter of $A$, ie the generator of $m$. We obtain a map $k[T] \to A, T \to t$, inducing $k[[T]] \to \widehat{A}$ after completion. How to prolonge it to $ \kappa_A[[T]]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $s\in m$ transcendental over $k$.

$K$ is a finite extension of $k(s)$ so $\widehat{K}$ is a finite extension of $k((s))$.

- Let $L/k((s))$ be the maximal unramified subextension of $\widehat{K}/k((s))$. By Hensel lemma we get $L = \kappa_A((s))$.
- $\widehat{K}/L$ is a tamely totally ramified finite extension, of degree $n$, so that $\widehat{K}=L((rs)^{1/n})$ for some $r\in \kappa_A^*$.
- ie. $$\widehat{K}= \kappa_A(((rs)^{1/n}))\cong \kappa_A((T))$$

Comment: why Hensel's lemma implies $ L = \kappa_A((s)) $? we know that unramified extensions correspond to finite separable extensions of the residue field. so $ L $ has residue field  $  \kappa_A $ and due to Hensel every element in $ \kappa_A $ has a unique preimage in $ L $ by lifting roots of minimal polynomials of elements of $  \kappa_A $. so as a set there lives a 'copy' of $  \kappa_A $ in $ L $. but why we can embed $ \kappa_A $ into $ L$ as field , not only as a set? ie why there exist a field monomorphism $ \kappa_A \subset L $ preserving the algebraic operations ?

Comment: Because of Hensel lemma. Take $a\in \kappa_A$, let $f\in k[x]$ be its minimal polynomial, by Hensel lemma $f$ has some root in $L$, so we can think to $a$ as an element of $L$ and repeat with $k(a)$ instead of $k$ @katalaveino

Comment: I think there is still a gap in the argument. Why do you think that $K $ is finite ext of $ k(s) $? $K $ was assumed to be a function field, so of course it might have transdeg bigger than one...

Comment: @katalaveino Yes I thought function field meant transcendence degree $1$. If bigger than one the proof will be quite different, the main step being to embed $k_A$ into $\widehat{A}$. Taking $v(s)>0$ then $\widehat{K}$ is a finite tame extension of $k_A((s))$.

Comment: do you see how to obtain this embedding of $\kappa_A$ into $\widehat{A}$? realizing $\widehat{A}$ projective limit it might be sufficient to construct a compatible family of maps from $\kappa_A$ to $A/m^n$. but I not know how to manage it. having this, the proof continues as you said exactly as before

Comment: for sake of completeness: the so called Cohen structure theorem proves the claim